# Como fazer a caixa abrir sem ser preciso o utilizador carregar no texto

Tags: php, javascript

Estou com um problema e não consigo remover o *click* para abrir a caixa de texto, eu quero deixar a caixa de texto sempre aberta e obrigatória, como faço isso?

Penso que o código é este:

```
html += '<div class="qstxt">
             <span onclick="$(\'#startMatter\').toggle();"   
                   title="Add a description of the question" class="q_editor jcmr-small" 
                   style="visibility:visible;margin-left:0;">Add a description of the question »
             </span>
             <textarea class="glotxtclass jcmr-hide " id="startMatter" style="margin-top:10px;" 
                       onfocus="$.focus(this,\'\',$.Q.replenish(this));" 
                       name="question_detail" title="Additional issue  Information...">
             </textarea>
        </div>';
```

Answer (score 1):

**Utilize o evento `onload`, exemplo:**

```
......
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
         $('body').onload(function() {
            $('startMatter').toggle();
            return false;
         });
      });   
   </script>
....
```

**Se houver uma div para ativar:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("q_editor jcmr-small").onload(function () {
            $(this).toggleClass("ativo").next().toggle();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Não consigo, encaixar isso no código, como ficaria  completo ? para fazer a substituição ?

Comment: ao menos tente fazer , não fique esperando que outros façam o seu serviço